# Repeat function on R

Tags: r, for-loop, rep

So my issue is the following: I'm trying to put together a list where each entry is a vector of multiple values simulated under a negative binomial distribution. I'm trying to use this code:

```
> test <- list()
> for(i in 1:100) {
+   test[[i]] <- rep(rnbinom(n=1000, size=36, prob=0.4), times = i, each =1)
+ }
```

However, I´m getting a list where the entries increase in size. Something like this:

```
int [1:1000] 33 82 44 33 58 45 63 ...
int [1:2000] 51 48 28 76 49 71 52 ...
int [1:3000] 59 53 65 72 38 41 48 ...
```

And so forth. In this case, I want every entry to have the same size (n=1000) but something is not quite right. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You actually don't need to use the `rep` function or a `for` loop. `test <- lapply(1:100, FUN = function(i) rbinom(1000, 36, 0.4))` will do what you want

Comment: @ bouncyball You're right, I keep forgetting about lapply... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually looking for `replicate`:

```
replicate(3,rnbinom(n=10, size=36, prob=0.4),F)
# [[1]]
# [1] 67 31 84 57 61 62 49 62 57 54
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 53 45 39 54 66 51 41 56 42 68
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 62 57 58 43 35 50 47 51 62 50
```